# Large number of small documents vs smaller number of large documents

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongodb to store data that as the following configuration (never mind the values)

```
{t:1, A:{1:[100, 22], 2:[100,22], 3:[100,22],... 20:[100,22]}, B:{1:[100, 22], 2:[100,22], 3:[100,22], 20:[100,22]}}
{t:2, A:{1:[100, 22], 2:[100,22], 3:[100,22],... 20:[100,22]}, B:{1:[100, 22], 2:[100,22], 3:[100,22], 20:[100,22]}}
...
{t:140.000, A:{1:[100, 22], 2:[100,22], 3:[100,22],... 20:[100,22]}, B:{1:[100, 22], 2:[100,22], 3:[100,22], 20:[100,22]}}
```

These documents are associated with a single activity and are similar to other activities which generate similar amounts of data, summing more than 100Mb per activity.

Some further notes:

a) I'd like to access parts of those documents, i.e., for example to get the documents with t in range {1000, 1001, ..., 10.000} so I'd certainly make an index on "t", using or not using a single document.

b) These documents are stored once and should not grow in size. Well, to be more precise, the truth is that the data will be produced along some time (more that 1 hour). And therefore the document would be increased ~140.000!

For some of you, certainly that the question is obvious: 
1. store them all in an array and use GridFS?
2. separated documents?

Best regards,
Pedro.

Comment: I actually don't find it that obvious at sure. Sure there is more than 16MB of data, but you say nothing much about the usage pattern other than writing. Since you cannot incrementally write a file in GridFS I would have thought that was obvious.

Comment: I forgot that! I could think on buffering and saving at the end but the database will serve as a channel of communication to other applications which will be processing the data in real time. So, "a lot of small documents" should be the answer... does any one desagree (why?)

Comment: Regarding that, and considering a lot of small docs and that the queries will always include the activity_id, after a few tests, a composed key _id:{activity_id:x, t:y} (creating a new composed index for that key) compared with a composed index on {"activity_id":x, "doc.t":y} seams a bit worst! any ideas why?

Comment: I really don't know based on part of a question posed within comments. Perhaps ask another question then, probably a good idea? The simple fact I was pointing out is you cannot incrementally update GridFS documents, so that point is invalid. Or you can look into what GridFS actually does and write your own interface.